# How is a well-received question defined?

Tags: support, badges

What are the technical criterion for a question to be defined as well-received? I am looking for the definition in context of the following badges:

- [Curious](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/badges/134/curious): Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a positive question record.
- [Inquisitive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/badges/135/inquisitive): Ask a well-received question on 30 separate days, and maintain a positive question record.
- [Socratic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/badges/136/socratic): Ask a well-received question on 100 separate days, and maintain a positive question record. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange, [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/295232):

> #### Curious
>
> - bronze; awarded once
> - Asked a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintained a positive question record
>
> #### Inquisitive
>
> - silver; awarded once
> - Asked a well-received question on 30 separate days, and maintained a positive question record
>
> #### Socratic
>
> - gold; awarded multiple times
> - Asked a well-received question on 100 separate days, and maintained a positive question record
>
>   - This badge can be earned multiple times, once every 100 qualifying days (e.g. once you accrue 200 qualifying days, you'll earn it a second time, provided you still have a positive question record).
>
> **Additional criteria for this badge family:**
>
> - There are four different counts that are tracked when calculating the criteria for this badge:
>
>   - Positive: Number of questions asked on this day that have a score greater than 0.
>   - Negative: Number of questions asked on this day that have a score less than 0.
>   - Closed: Number of questions asked on this day that are currently closed and the current closure date occurred within 60 days of being asked.
>   - Deleted: Number of questions asked on this day that are currently deleted and the current deletion date occurred within 60 days of being asked.
> - Any day that has at least one Positive question *and* also has no Negative, Closed, or Deleted questions counts as a "qualifying day" which increments the counter.
> - A positive question record means you don't have too many Closed, Negative, or Deleted questions overall. The formula is `(TotalQuestions - Negative - Closed - Deleted) / TotalQuestions ≥ 0.5`. Questions that qualify as Negative *and* Closed *and* Deleted count three times in this calculation!